# How should I approach my EC2 contingency plan?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I've browsed through other questions on SO concerning backing up EC2, and it has provided me with a good basis, but I'm still a bit confused as to how I should approach my solution and develop a contingency plan. Most questions are fairly specific, but I have a pretty vanilla setup, and I think this information will be beneficial to future users. Let me provide my basic setup:

- Basic small instance
- Pushing files to S3
- Running MongoDB
- Running nginx

Now, due to the ephemeral nature of EC2, it's apparent that I need to bind my EC2 instance to EBS to ensure persistent storage. The reason I'm attempting to develop a contingency plan is that I'm worried my instance may disappear at any time (due to outages, etc). If my instance were to disappear, I'm concerned that I would have to spin up a new instance and reinstall all my applications before getting everything up an running again. A few questions:

- How do I backup my instance to ensure that if it were to disappear, I could quickly bring it back up (preferably without having to reinstall all previous software)? I don't need a series of backups, just the previous days (or weeks) backup to ensure that a previous working version exists that can be started quickly.
- If I use EBS instead of instance storage, it essentially acts in place of my hard drive right? So if I have MongoDB installed, I'm assuming the database it is writing to cab placed on EBS?
- If I go with the small instance with 160 GB of storage and I use EBS, would I need to allocate 160 GB of EBS out of the gate, or is the 160 GB for instance storage only?

So, in summary, I would like a solution (either manual or automatic) that can create a snapshot of my EC2 instance to ensure that if it were to disappear, it could be reconstructed without having to spend the time to manually reconstruct everything.

In an ideal world, if my instance were to disappear, I could spin up an version of my instance  with everything intact (to a point where things were backed up). Any resources or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here we go:

For backups:

1. Create your instance from one of the stock AWS images. Make sure it is an EBS-backed VM - depending on the size of the VM you pick, you'll get a volume assigned with 'n' GB of space, attached as the boot volume (/dev/sda1).
2. Configure the VM with whatever software you need, apply patches, tune for disk fragmentation, CPU consumption (task priorities, etc), and any other configuration you need that makes the VM tailored to your requirements.
3. Stop the VM and take a snapshot of the EBS volume, then restart it (re-assigning the Elastic IP is there is one). This is your backup snapshot - repeat as desired at whatever frequency you like. Remember to stop the VM when you snap it to prevent the OS writing to the volume whilst you're taking a copy of it.

For recovery:

1. Your VM will fail, eventually. You'll break something and render it damaged or inoperative, or the hardware it's running on will suffer a fault. It will happen.
2. When it does, terminate it (if it didn't self-terminate) and spin-up a new VM of the same type from the AWS stock list. Wait until it shows as 'Running', and then stop it.
3. Detach its EBS volume and delete it.
4. Create a new EBS volume from whichever backup snapshot you last created, and attach that new volume to the VM as /dev/sda1.
5. Start the VM and assign your EIP if appropriate.

About EBS storage:

1. It's a chunk of storage space. If you format it to look like a standard disk, you can use it exactly as you would a physical disk. Install stuff on it, point software at it for use as storage space, whatever.

Comment: Nice recovery/backups plan, but stills without an environment backup plan, since EBS does not preserve you EC2 preferences, right ?

Comment: Excellent response. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: First, if your EC2 fail, it'll fail the hole instance, not only the EBS. So you will need to recreate the hole EC2, which cannot be created by EBS directly. You will need to create an AMI by EBS snapshot and after an EC2 by the AMI. So any CloudWatch alarm or anything you have associated with that instance will need to be re set. If you have one main private AMI, you will be able to reference this AMI ID and have a quick recover plan.

Comment: I think by 'recreate the hole EC2' you mean 're-instantiate the VM'. This CAN be done without the use of a custom AMI, as my answer describes. Furthermore, CloudWatch alarms (like Elastic IP addresses) if used will need to be applied to any new instance, regardless of whether it is a recovery scenario or simply an addition to your estate. Unless you are using a 3rd-party or homegrown tool to manage this, it will always have to be done manually - there is no AWS-provided mechanism to automate it.

Comment: Ah, the old 'random unexplained downvote', three years after the answer was accepted. Proof that whilst there may be intelligent life in the Universe, it's pretty scarce on Earth.

Answer (score 1):

you have two options: (BUT NOT EXACTLY AS YOU WANT ;( )

1- Have an 'external' EBS attached into your EC2 instance, and manually (you can do  automatically through cronjobs), make snapshots from it ! But it's not what you want, why ? If your EC2 instance disappears, you will need to re-create all your environment again and re-attach your EBS... So it's a nice way of having backups of HUGE datas on your EC2, but your enviroment is destructed...

2- The best way, but not so perfect, is after you finished configuring your EC2, make a private AMI from it, so anytime you want you can launch more instances like that , from that AMI, so everything is cloned.... BUT the worst part of it, is that every time you change a configuration from the instance, you still need to make a new AMI, and every time you make a new AMI, you need to reboot your instance to grant data integrity on your new private AMI !

I recommend you to take a closer look into RESERVED EC2 instances, that have a better stability from normal ones. BUT YOU STILL CAN HAVE HARDWARE DISASTERS as normal instances too...

Comment: 1) remember to quiesce the OS before taking the snapshot to prevent writes occurring during the snap. 2) AMIs are useful as baseline OS templates - for more dynamically-changing VMs, use the snapshot process described in my answer. 3) Reserved instances are no more 'stable' than spot- or on-demand instances - they exist on exactly the same hardware platform, but have a different cost model because you pay 'up-front'.